# How to insert elements in an array using a function?

Tags: arrays, c, function, insert

I'm having a bit of a hard time trying to make a function in `C` that has 2 parameters, the name of an array and the initial size of it, and checks the array for odd numbers. If it finds one, it will `insert` its double right next to it and move the rest of the elements. I know how to do this without a function, but with a function, it doesnt work. The program is running, but its doing nothing. Some help, please?

Ex. `a[5]= {2, 5, 6, 8, 11};`

```
 a[7]={2, 5, 10, 6, 8, 11, 22}
```

Also, the function must not return anything and the array is indexed from 0 to n-1.

This is what my function looks like.

```
void Insert(int v[], int *n)    
{
    int i,j;
    
    for(i=*n-1; i>=0; i--)     //passing through the array from right to left
    {
        if(v[i]%2==1)       // if the element is odd
        {
            *n++;           // grow the array size by 1 
            int double=v[i]*2;    
            for(j=*n-1; j>=i+1; j--)    // move all elements in the right of the odd number to the right by 1 space
            {
                v[j+1]=v[j];
            }
            v[i+1]=double;    // add the double value next space after the odd number.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what specific problem or incorrect results you have. "seems to be a different story" doesn't tell us anything specific. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: double is a very bad name for a variable, not sure this even compiles

Comment: you need to allocate some memory to be able to grow an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the memory allocated for v is big enough to support the growth (see the 32 into the main function), you have 2 issues:

- double is a reserved word
- *n++ is not doing what you need, this increment the n pointer not its value

```
static void Insert(int v[], int *n)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=*n-1; i>=0; i--)     //passing through the array from right to left
    {
        if(v[i]%2==1)       // if the element is odd
        {
            (*n)++;           // grow the array size by 1
            int d=v[i]*2;
            for(j=*n-1; j>=i+1; j--)    // move all elements in the right of the odd number to the right by 1 space
            {
                v[j+1]=v[j];
            }
            v[i+1]=d;    // add the d value next space after the odd number.
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int a[32]= {2, 5, 6, 8, 11};
    int len = 5;
    Insert(a, &len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The output is:

> 2 5 10 6 8 11 22

Comment: Oh, damn. I didn't used double in my program but its translation in my native language which is accepted by C. I then translated my whole program in english so its easier to understand and forgot about double being a data type. 
So basically the only error was the way i tried to increment the value. The compiler didnt complay so i thought its alright. But i get it now. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

**Issues:**

- `double` is a reserved keyword in c.
- Actually from the question I feel you don't have enough memory to store the elements, and you are not increasing the size.
- *n++ is equivalent to *(n++), but you need to do is (*n)++

Okay, If the memory is large enough to store all the elements, then you can use the other answer. If not you can use this code :

Then you need to use `realloc` to change the size time to time. So for that your array should be created dynamically. And you should send the pointer to pointer to the array (`int **`) to the function as you can see in the below code. These changes all are done based on how `realloc` works.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Insert(int **v, int *n)
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = (*n) - 1; i >= 0; i--)     //passing through the array from right to left
    {
        if((*v)[i] % 2 == 1)       // if the element is odd
        {
            while (1) {
                int *p = realloc(*v, (*n + 1) * sizeof(int));         // grow the array size by 1
                if (p != NULL) {
                    *v = p;
                    (*n)++;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Allocation failed .... Reallocating\n");
                    continue;
                }
            }

            int var = (*v)[i] * 2;
            for(j = (*n) - 1; j >= i + 2; j--)    // move all elements in the right of the odd number to the right by 1 space
            {
                (*v)[j] = (*v)[j - 1];
            }
            (*v)[i + 1] = var;    // add the double value next space after the odd number
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size = 3;
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        a[i] = i + 1;

    Insert(&a, &size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }

    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is quite complicated for me as i havent reached the subject of allocating memory yet. But thanks a lot for taking time to answer my question. I will come back here when i have a better understanding of this matter and it will help me more then.